# First page blank in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I have crystal report. I have grouping in fields.

I have set NewPageAfter = true for group. i supressed page header.. still i am getting first page blank in report..

how can i solve this issue?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is your group on more than one page and you checked to keep the section unified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NewPageAfter=true` needs to be set at the "bottom" of the group; in the footer.  If you set it in the group header it will print the header and then force a page break.

Make sure it is also not ticked on any of the headers above it and ensure `"NewPageBefore"` is un-ticked in the group details.

You should also try un-ticking `"Keep Together"` - as this will allow crystal to split the group over multiple pages.